# Problema al conectar Yii2 con SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, yii2

Estoy tratando de conectar mi aplicacion en Yii2 con una base de datos en SQL Server, la version que estoy usando es la 10.0, este es mi mensaje de error:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].

Archivo de configuracion

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=softwareoperacional',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'admin123',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Tienes instalado el Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server? yo también tuve el mismo error instalando el driver se soluciono.